# neo4j and mahout comparison

Tags: neo4j, mahout, recommendation-engine

I am working on building a recommendation system.

And I found that neo4j and mahout are the best available solution for building recommendation system.

But I am unable to clearly distinguish between the advantage and issues related to these two.

Could anyone provide me a comparison between neo4j and mahout ?

Which is best for building a recommendation system ?

Comment: I think reco4.com uses both mahout and Neo4j, perhaps you can check there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a deep question that can't be specifically answered without a lot more information about what kind of recommendation system you want, what kind of scalability you need, what your hardware/software/platform configuration looks like, and so on.

But let me give you this to consider:  the issue isn't a comparison of neo4j and mahout, it's a comparison between neo4j and hadoop.   Mahout would generally run on top of a hadoop infrastructure, so all of the assumptions and implementation constraints that come with hadoop are for the most part more important to consider than just the raw graph layer implementation differences.

You should read up more on hadoop - the approach it takes to data storage and management is completely different than what neo4j does.  Both have their pros and cons, and entire books can and have been written about the pros and cons of the approach hadoop takes.   The brief version is that if you need massive scalability and you have huge datasets, hadoop is set up to work well in those environments; neo4j doesn't promise scalability beyond billions or tens of billions of nodes, and the kinds of scalability that it does promise are quite different than hadoop.

You should do some more reading on this topic, or further refine your question to prevent people from getting into opinionated flamewars about what is better.  Maybe there is a better choice for you in consideration of all of your details, but we don't have those details.

Comment: thank you @FrobberOfBits , I am new to this area and I am experimenting with mahout and neo4j. And as far as i know scalability is the main issue neo4j. But the advantage is the power of graph database. is that right ? But mahout require data to be presented is some particular format (like csv). So is it advisable to use mahout in top of neo4j to build collaborative filtering ?

Comment: Scalability isn't really the main point of a graph database, that's more of a separate issue.  Hadoop gives you one kind of scalability, neo4j a different kind of scalability.  Let me stress that in order to discuss this in a helpful way, people would need more information about your situation.

Comment: I have a list user data : user name, age, sex , address, location etc and a set of product data : Product name, Cost , description etc
Now i would like to build a recommendation engine that will be able to : 1 Figure out similar products, 2 Recommend relevant products for the product list to user